# SQL Server 2005 Column Type to store LatLng Coordinates

Tags: sql-server-2005, geocoding

In SQL Server 2005 what column type should I use to store a LatLng Coordinate?

For example a Lat coordinate like 135.0058554

I know there are new types in SQL Server 2008 but I'm stuck with SQL Server 2005 for the time being.

thanks

Comment: The first question to answer is: What format are you going to store the Lat/Long in - "Degrees, Minutes and Seconds", "Degrees and Decimal Minutes", "Decimal Degrees"?

Comment: Good point. I will be storing them as degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Use Decimal.

For example:

`Decimal(18,15)` for high precision.

Answer (score 0):

We're using numeic (12,8) and haven't had any problems with 55,000 Australian geocoded addresses.

Answer (score 0):

We use "float" (8 bytes/15 digits), which has adequate (~micron) resolution for most needs and good performance/storage efficiency.

W.r.t. @OMG Ponies' point, I'm a proponent of signed decimal degrees over DMS.

p.s. a latitude of 135.0058554 is REALLY REALLY far north! :-)